# Add filename into one of the column in BigQuery native table

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Multiple files whose file names containing timestamp in GCS. Have to read all those data from each file and insert those data into BigQuery table along with timestamp as one of the column. How to achieve that in DAG?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a cloud function with a cron job from `Cloud Scheduler` :

- Read files from a bucket
- Parse the timestamp from each filename
- write the result dict for each file to Bigquery

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage

bucket_name = 'mybucket'
folder='/projects/bigquery/download/shakespeare/'
delimiter='/'
file = 'shakespeare'

# Retrieve all blobs with a prefix matching the file.
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket=storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

# List blobs iterate in folder 
blobs=bucket.list_blobs(prefix=file, delimiter=delimiter) # Excluding folder inside bucket
for blob in blobs:
   print(blob.name)
   destination_uri = '{}/{}'.format(folder, blob.name) 
   element_as_str = blob.download_as_string() # or download_as_string
   
   element_as_dict = json.loads(element_as_str)
 
   # Then parse timestamp from the filename : blob.name

   # Use Bigquery Python client to write data containing the timestamp as dict to a Bigquery table
   client = bigquery.Client()
   client.insert_rows_json(f'{dataset}.{table}', element_as_dict)
```

You can also do the same logic with a Python Beam/Dataflow cron job from Cloud Scheduler :

```py
PCollection<KV<String, String>> filesAndLines = 
  p.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern('bucket_path/*.csv'))
   .apply(FileIO.read())
   .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<ReadableFile, KV<String, String>>() {
     @ProcessElement
     public void process(ProcessContext c) {
       ReadableFile f = c.element();
       String filename = f.getMetadata().resourceId().toString();
       String line;
       try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(Channels.newInputStream(f.open()))) {
         while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
           c.output(KV.of(filename, line));
         }
       }
     }
   }));
```

You can apply your own logic in the couple `file_name => line` and write the result to BigQuery via `BigQueryIO`

I think the cloud function solution is more lightweight, but I wanted to show this solution anyway.
If you have to parse a big amount of files and your job duration will exceed one hour, the `Beam` solution can be interesting because Cloud function V2 is limited to one hour.